# Grouping and Sum Datatable by two fields with different Where conditions

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a datatable with sample data like below.

```
UserName    IsBillable    Hours
-----------------------------
user1       Yes           10
user2       Yes           15
user3       No            20
user1       Yes           25
user1       No            15
user2       Yes           10
```

And I want to group by `IsBillable` and sum with `Hours` column.

```
UserName    Billable    NonBillable
-----------------------------
user1       35           15
user2       25           0
user3       0            20
```

How can I do this with using `LINQ` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var grouped = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(row=> row.Field<string>("UserName"))
                .Select(gr=> new 
                {
                    UserName = gr.Key,
                    Billable = gr.Where(row=>row.Field<string>("IsBillable")=="Yes")
                                 .Sum(row=>row.Field<int>("Hours"),
                    NonBillable = gr.Where(row=>row.Field<string>("IsBillable")=="No")
                                    .Sum(row=>row.Field<int>("Hours"),
                });
```

I have assumed that `dt` is your DataTable and you just need a sequence of items with three properties `UserName`, `Billable`, `NonBillable`. If you need your result to be a DataTable, you need some extra work. Please let me know, if that's the case.

What we are doing above, it's straightforward. Intially we group our results based on the user's name and then we filter the items of each group, in order to calculate the corresponding sums.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your answer solved my problem. @Christos

Comment: @YusufDuyar you are welcome dude ! I am glad that I helped :)