# Doing Calculations of a group

Tags: c#

I have a Visual Studio Program where the user enters specific data of production for that day. Example:

```
Date      | Part Number | Mold Num | Machine Num |  Total Parts  |Cycle  
2/12/2016 | 1185-5B8    |  6580    | 12          |   220         |  56  
2/12/2016 | 2249300     |  7797    | 36          |   600         |  13  
2/12/2016 | 146865      |  5096789 | 56          |   500         |  15  
2/16/2016 | 123456      |  7787    | 54          |   300         |  34  
2/16/2016 | 123456      |  787     | 54          |   360         |  36  
2/16/2016 | 123456      |  777     | 54          |   500         |  46  
2/16/2016 | 123456      |  87      | 54          |   400         |  44
```

I'm trying to have people enter production data and then manipulate it in order to get the machine usage (MU) (Equation: Total Parts/(3600/Cycle). I want to get these things for each day and for a specific month when I call it. I looked at what others have done but they are just counting how many are in a specific date but I need to multiply, and divide other columns together in two different tables with the same dates in order to get what I need.

Example output:

```
2/12/2016: MU = 41.12%
2/16/2016: MU = 24.79%
February:  MU = 32.96%
```

EDIT:

I would like to do something in the lines of this example but I do not know how to implement it to an already existing DataSet.

[Grouping and Sum Datatable by two fields with different Where conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32047225/grouping-and-sum-datatable-by-two-fields-with-different-where-conditions)

or this example:

[Calculating percentage of a groups from datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645557/calculating-percentage-of-a-groups-from-datatable)

Comment: In SQL you can use CTE to make this happen : with x
as
(select date, Avg(TotalParts) MU group by date )
select date,MU
union all
select DATEPART(date,MONTH) date, Avg(MU) MU
group by DATEPART(date,MONTH) .. something like this

Comment: @Sam.C Then how would I implement those values that I get into my Visual Studio program

Comment: are you using EF or any ORM for your database operation?

Comment: Just use plain LINQ (to objects)

Comment: @Sam.C I am using ORM

Comment: @leppie is there an example that I could possibly follow because I do not know much about LINQ to objects. I have looked for some but none are doing what I want to do